# trigger or return shift+tab in javascript or JQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation, keycode, shift

I made a page for a windows CE with a two dimentional navigation using tabIndex. at first I just wanted to use tabIndex as a reference for the next focus.

because this application is for a portable device, doing it like this is very demanding on the handheld and very time consuming when comparing to a simple tab and shift+tab.

I have a function to process the onkeydown for my up arrow and down arrow,
for my downarrow, the code is simple

`if(specialMove == 0){`all this does is checks that the tab isn't leaving the page.

`event.keyCode=9;    return;}`

the problem is my uparrow, I want it to return a SHIFT+TAB to navigate upwards, I found this snipet of jQuery code but I'm having a problem making it work.

```
if(specialMove == 0){
    $('body').trigger(JQuery.Event('keydown', {keyCode:9, shiftKey: true}));
    return;
}
```

Comment: What CE version / device / browser are you using?

Comment: CE 2.0 if I remember right, MC9090 and IE6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger only calls the event handlers defined on the body in this case. It does not send the key codes to the browser. See: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/. In short, it only executes the code that jQuery knows of that would be executed in case of a keydown event. It 'simulates' a keydown event.

Sending key events to the browser is not possible as far as I know, as this poses some serious security risks. You'll have to implement selecting the next and previous element in Javascript.

EDIT:
You could try something like:

```
$(function() {
  var navigationElements = $('[tabIndex]').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).attr('tabindex') - $(b).attr('tabindex');
  });

  // We don't know if the users presses the up or down button first
  // so we initialize as null and let the event handle the first element
  var currentIndex = null;

  // On event:
  if (currentIndex != null && currentIndex < navigationElements.length - 1) {
    navigationElements[++currentIndex].focus();
  } else {
    currentIndex = 0;
    navigationElements[currentIndex].focus();
  }

  // and:
  if (currentIndex != null && currentIndex > 0) {
    navigationElements[--currentIndex].focus();
  } else {
    currentIndex = navigationElements.length - 1;
    navigationElements[currentIndex].focus();
  }
});
```

This is untested, unoptimized code, so there probably is a much better solution but this would work pretty fast even on slow browsers. It does not take into account focus changes that do not go through your events, so you'd have to add `onfocus` events to set the `currentIndex` to the element that was lastly selected by the user.

Comment: But you could probably use the event to find the previous (or next) input, sorted by tabIndex, and move focus there.  Actually that would probably be very useful for a mobile site for a non-touch phone.

Comment: I doubt that, since the next or previous element will never get selected. You'll have to find all elements that can be selected, order them by position in the DOM and / or tab index, and then move up and down the tree relative to the currently selected item. Trivial to do on a desktop or a modern mobile browser, but Windows CE? I'm not so sure...

Comment: that's what I am doing right now, my tabs are sorted by tabindex and I search for the next tab index using `$('[tabIndex='+currIndex+']').focus();` but doing it this way gives a lag of about a second which is way too long to use, I dont know if getelementbyid or class is a faster way to search than my jquery command.

Comment: You could try caching a list of all elements in an array after the page loads and iterate over it: `elements[currentIndex++].focus()`. This prevents the DOM operation every click. You only need to keep track of manual focus changes by the user (if possible on the browser).

Comment: I can't get that navigationElements to function, this is what I have for my code (simplified) all I did is change `$('[tabIndex=currIndex]')` to `navigationElements[currIndex].focus();` and navigationElements
my code:


`  var navigationElements = $('[tabIndex]').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).attr('tabindex') - $(b).attr('tabindex');
  });  


function navig()
{
  

currIndex=document.activeElement.tabIndex;  


  if(event.keyCode == 38)
   currIndex--;
  
 else if(event.keyCode == 40){

   event.keyCode=9;
   return;
   }
   
  
 navigationElements[currIndex].focus();
 }`

Comment: Can you check if `navigationElements` is properly filled? Is the event properly triggered and does the currIndex correspond with the index you expect at that time? Why do you change the `event.keyCode`? It seems you can just do `currIndex++` instead.

Comment: I could just to currIndex but for now I'll keep it at code 9 just to check that it reads properly.
the navigation Element seems properly filled based on alerts I do. I tried a bit more and it seems to half work on chrome without the ecceptions (my code is adapted for currindex to be the value of the tabindexes so it is a bit buggy). 
however I get nothing in windows which is the platform I have to work on. might be that my browser is not compatible with that string of code.

Comment: windows could not read
`  var navigationElements = $('[tabindex]').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).attr('tabIndex') - $(b).attr('tabIndex');
  });`
but chrome can, so it might be a command that windows can't handle properly.

Comment: I can't test IE6 on CE, so you'll have to debug that statement by statement to figure out where it's going wrong. First try to get the list of elements, then see if it gets properly sorted. Good luck!

Comment: it can read part of the element, oddly enough it can see the value, but it can't see the tabindex of that element. even though that's what I searched it by.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keyupEvent = new Event('KeyboardEvent');
keyupEvent.initEvent('keyup');
Object.defineProperties(keyupEvent, {
  keyCode: {
    value: 9
  },
  shiftKey: {
    value: true
  }
});

...

element.dispatch(keyupEvent);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: In typescript, it will htmlelement.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);